# width of a <span> appended dynamically in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, width

Well this seems quite simple but i'm not able to figure out what is going wrong here. I have appended a `<span>` dynamically as follows:
`$("#parent").append("<span style='display:inline-block; position:absolute; background:yellow; z-index:10; top:12px;' id='mathBox"+flag_id+"'></span>");`

Now i need to find the width of this `<span>` when pressing a certain key (TAB in my case!).
Initially i tried jquery like this:
`var width_of_text= $("'mathBox'+flag_id").width();
alert(width_of_text);`
But this is showing an error in console that this expression is not identified (Even i was feeling that something is not right here!!)
Then i tried using vanila JS as follows:
`var mathBox_id=document.getElementById('mathBox'+flag_id);
var width_of_text= mathBox_id.offsetWidth;
alert(width_of_text);`

Now this worked fine but it is showing me wrong width. `<span>` element present on DOM (at the time of testing it), is barely of 25 width however it is showing its width as 111 width.
I know i must be doing something stupid but i'm just not able to catch it..
Please help!!

Comment: You used variable as string. Use: `$('mathBox'+flag_id)`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Thanks for pointing that out, guess that was a typo error by me!! Sorry!

Comment: why this has been downvoted? Am i not supposed to ask questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the jQuery version is

```
var width_of_text= $('#mathBox'+flag_id).width();
alert(width_of_text);
```

Comment: Aah... i'd say that really was a silly mistake of mine! Thanks

Comment: But i'm still not able to get the correct width. :(

Comment: @TusharShukla You've not defined the width for the element. You need to define it explicitly.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal But the content would be dynamic, can be of any width, if i give an explicit width to it then it would be kinda fixed..right?

Comment: Because you use absolute positioning. Or, you may define left and right values. Then get the width by js.

Answer (score 0):

`var width_of_text= $('mathBox'+flag_id).width();` use `#` symbol with id.

`var width_of_text= $('#mathBox'+flag_id).width();`